# Convert dynamic rows to columns with sql select (Mysql Server)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "Organisation" :

[image]

And table when we find the other setting of organisation "setting" (is not fixed):

[image]

And the last table is "setting_value"  where we found the value of the 3 organisation :

[image]

I need to create a view to give me this result

```
IdOrganisation | LibelleOrganisation | DateCreation | DateModification | Mail | Tel | Pays | Code Postal | Ville | Adresse | Logo | Secteur

62 | Prevealys | 2016-10-11 10:40:24| 2016-10-11 10:40:24 | mail@gmail.com  | 002122222222 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL

68 | Solutions Conduite d'activité | 2016-11-01 15:06:32 | 2016-11-01 15:06:32 | NULL | NULL | Tunisie | NULL | NULL | Borj Baccouche Ariana | NULL | NULL
```

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? You may want to take a look to the *PIVOT* operator.

Comment: I used PHP to do the join but with more than 5000 lines the loading became very slow

Comment: _PIVOT_ will definitely help you. Good luck as it is not the simplest relational operator!

Comment: Yes I confirm :'(